# Serilog, File sink, changing output Template

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I'm trying to set up serilog in some new projects. The problem is we have some legacy projects that use different custom logging solutions and I need logs to be in the same format as the old ones.

I'm using json configuration like this:

```
 "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId", "WithAssemblyName", "WithAssemblyVersion" ],
 "WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "C:\\Logs\\EmailingService\\log.json",
      "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
      "rollingInterval": "Day"
    }
  }
]
```

What I want is to change the output format of the Json file.
I discovered [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/31) that I cannot use outputTemplate with JsonFormatter.

Right now my logs are like this:

```
{"Timestamp":"2020-07-17T07:34:36.4201803+02:00","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"Server instance started.","Properties":{"SourceContext":"DataSharingLibrary.Server.PipeServer","MachineName":"NTB","ProcessId":28024,"ThreadId":5,"AssemblyName":"EmalingService","AssemblyVersion":"1.0.0.0"}}
```

What I want is to move global enrichers out of the "properties" like this:

```
{"Timestamp":"2020-07-17T07:34:36.4201803+02:00","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"Server instance started.", "SourceContext":"DataSharingLibrary.Server.PipeServer","MachineName":"NTB","ProcessId":28024,"ThreadId":5,"AssemblyName":"EmalingService","AssemblyVersion":"1.0.0.0", "Properties":{...} }
```

What are my options?
Do I have to write completly new ITextWritter for that? Use Nlog instead??

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/RenderedCompactJsonFormatter.cs is very close to what you're after, and is only a couple of dozen SLoC that should be easily copyable/modifiable, if that's an option for you. HTH!